# Add Conditions to Resources in CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

I have created a CDK stack that will be deployed in multiple regions. One of the constructs shall only be deployed in one region. In Cloudformation I'd simply add a Condition to the resource, but I haven't found a way to do something similar with CDK constructs.

It is possible to define a `CfnCondition` and add it to `CfnResource`s, but I how do I add conditions to constructs like lambda functions?

Comment: use `if` statements in your code to conditionally create the resource?

Comment: The region isn't known at synth-time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a example on how to achieve this for a `iam.User`:

```ts
// Create a CloudFormation condition on the region
const regionCondition = new cdk.CfnCondition(this, 'RegionCondition', {
  expression: cdk.Fn.conditionEquals(cdk.Stack.of(this).region, 'eu-west-1'),
});

// Create the user using the L2 construct
const user = new iam.User(this, 'User');

// Add the condition on the underlying AWS::IAM::User
(user.node.defaultChild as iam.CfnUser).cfnOptions.condition = regionCondition
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. Do you know where I can find this in the documentation?

Comment: You have examples here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/core-readme.html#intrinsic-functions-and-condition-expressions and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/core-readme.html#resource-options (the last one is missing a `cfnOptions`, just opened a PR to fix this https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/5490)

Comment: How could I have missed that? Sometimes the answers hide in plain sight... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example on how to achieve this for a `iam.Role`:

```
const role = new iam.Role(this, "TestRole", {...});

const conditionKey = "AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement.0.Condition.ForAnyValue:StringLike";


const conditionValue = {
      "aws:userid": [
        "user1@company.com",
        "user2@company.com",
      ],
    };

const roleRef = role.node.defaultChild as iam.CfnRole;
roleRef.addPropertyOverride(conditionKey, conditionValue);
```