# AWS CDK: Add Cfn Condition to all/multiple resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-cdk

I need to add a condition (e.g. `isProd` or `isSpecificRegion`) to all/multiple of my resources in CDK.  I saw that I can add a `CfnCondition` to a specific CDK resources using this technique: [Add Conditions to Resources in CDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411734/add-conditions-to-resources-in-cdk). e.g.

```
// Create the user using the L2 construct
const user = new iam.User(this, 'User');

// Add the condition on the underlying AWS::IAM::User
(user.node.defaultChild as iam.CfnUser).cfnOptions.condition = regionCondition
```

Is there a way to iterate over all resources and apply a condition?

Comment: You use typescript, why not using simple `if\else\foreach` for these kinds of things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [CDK Aspects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/aspects.html) ([as suggested by Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61083571/117750)) I was able to simply my solution even further (building upon my previous solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61234581/117750):

```kotlin
class ApplyCfnConditionAspect(val cfnCondition: CfnCondition): IAspect {
    override fun visit(construct: IConstruct) {
        (construct as? CfnResource)?.cfnOptions?.condition = this.cfnCondition
    }
}
```

... and then within the `Stack`, after specifying all the resources:

```kotlin
this.node.applyAspect(ApplyCfnConditionAspect(shouldEnableAnalyticsCondition))
```

Comment: the applyAspect code seems to run after your code has executed, so you can add it first or last in your stack - you will still apply the aspect to all nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you don't want to use the CfnConditional with CDK unless there is a very specific need. As Amit mentioned in their comment, the idiomatic CDK appraoch would be to use the language's if/else logic to either instantiate a construct or not.

If you absolutely **need** to use CFNConditional on every Resource, I think that the aspects feature could apply the conditional to the underlying cloudformation resources using escape hatches, though I would **strongly** advise against this.

Comment: Thanks - I found out a couple of ways of getting this done (see my responses here), and eventually settled on using an Aspect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61236670/117750

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to automatically apply a [CfnCondition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/core/cfncondition.html#core_CfnCondition) to every resource in the stack using the [Construct#onPrepare](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/core/construct.html#core_Construct_onPrepare) hook in the [Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/core/stack.html#core_Stack)

From the above page, `Construct#onPrepare()` is:

> Perform final modifications before synthesis
>
> This method can be implemented by derived constructs in order to perform final changes before synthesis. prepare() will be called after child constructs have been prepared.
>
> This is an advanced framework feature. Only use this if you understand the implications.

The following CDK code (example code - I only put in the relevant bits here) is in [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) but
 would apply to any
 supported CDK
 language:

```kotlin
class MyStack internal constructor(app: App, name: String) : Stack(app, name) {
      private lateinit var myCondition: CfnCondition

    init {
        myCondition = CfnCondition.Builder.create(this, "myCondition")
                .expression(Fn.condition...) // Fill in your condition
                .build()
    }

    /**
     * Use the `Stack#onPrepare` hook to find all CF resources and apply our stack standard CF condition on them.
     * See:
     * * [Stack.onPrepare]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/core/construct.html#core_Construct_onPrepare
     */
    override fun onPrepare() {
        super.onPrepare()
        findAllCfnResources(this.node).forEach { it.cfnOptions.condition = this.myCondition }
    }

    /**
     * Recurse through all children nodes and accumulate [CfnResource] nodes.
     */
    private fun findAllCfnResources(node: ConstructNode): List<CfnResource> {
        val nodes = node.children.map { it.node } + node
        val cfnResources: List<CfnResource> = nodes.flatMap { it.findAll() }.mapNotNull { it as? CfnResource }

        if (node.children.isEmpty()) {
            return cfnResources
        }

        return node.children.fold(cfnResources) {
            accumulatedCfnResources, it -> accumulatedCfnResources + findAllCfnResources(it.node)
        }
    }
}
```

A unit-test (Junit and AssertJ, also in Kotlin) I added verifies that this covers all resources:

```kotlin
private val mapper = ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)

private lateinit var stack: Stack
private lateinit var synthesizedStackCfTemplate: JsonNode

@BeforeEach
fun setUp() {
    val app = App()
    stack = MyStack(app, "MyUnitTestStack")
    synthesizedStackCfTemplate = mapper.valueToTree(app.synth().getStackArtifact(stack.artifactId).template)
}

@Test
fun `All CfnResources have the expected CF Condition`() {
    val expectedCondition = "myCondition"

    val softly = SoftAssertions()
    synthesizedStackCfTemplate.get("Resources").forEach { resource ->
        softly.assertThat(resource.get("Condition")?.asText())
                .describedAs("Resource is missing expected CF condition [$expectedCondition]: $resource")
                .isEqualTo(expectedCondition)
    }
    softly.assertAll()
}
```