# Add Condition to AwsCustomResource

Tags: aws-cdk

This excellent question provides two methods for adding conditions to resources.

[Add Conditions to Resources in CDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411734/add-conditions-to-resources-in-cdk)

However, an AwsCustomResource has neither an underlying CfnConstruct nor an addPropertyOverride() method.

How would one add a condition to an AwsCustomResource?

Comment: Do you need this because you're manually deploying the synthed templates? Why not use `if` and let `cdk deploy` deal with this for you?

Comment: I have a AwsCustomResource in a stack I only want to run when the stack is deployed under specific conditions. It could be as simple as different environment, for example dev & test, for discussion purposes.

Comment: You can check that in your CDK code. For example you can set a context item named `stage` and change your deployment based on it. Then use `-c stage=prod` when deploying.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Typescript, this is possible. I assume it is possible for other languages as well if we use similar casting tricks.

In the CDK Github, we see that AwsCustomResource has an underlying CustomResource member: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/d7e4b7a7009aa03a81902266313c521b12b12d25/packages/aws-cdk-lib/custom-resources/lib/aws-custom-resource/aws-custom-resource.ts#L397

We also see that CustomResource has an underlying CfnResource member: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/d7e4b7a7009aa03a81902266313c521b12b12d25/packages/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/custom-resource.ts#L126

CfnResource is the class that provides the cfnOptions member where you can set a resource's condition. Both `AwsCustomResource.customResource` and `CustomResource.resource` have private visibility, but we can circumvent this by casting the objects to `any`. When all is said and done:

```
(((myCustomResource as any).customResource as any).resource as CfnResource).cfnOptions.condition = myCondition;
```